# How to generate a random number each time a component re-renders?

Tags: css, reactjs, less

I want to use Less variables to generate a random number for conditionally class that gets added and removed each second. Here is the sample code of reactjs file

```
function App() {
  const [date , setDate] = useState('')
  const [circleBoolean, setCircleBoolean] = useState(false);
  const [random_number, setRandom_number] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      doThings()
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  function doThings() {
    setCircleBoolean((prev)=>{
      return !prev});
    setDate(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')) ;
    setRandom_number(Math.random() * 100);
    console.log("cirlce boolean :" + circleBoolean)
  }



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="bg">
        <div style={{ top:`${random_number}%`, left:`${random_number}%` }}  className={circleBoolean ? "circle" : ""} />
        <div className="card">
          <p className="card-info">{date}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is the sample code from css file

```
@color: blue;
@random: (round(`Math.random()`)) ;

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 4px @color;
  border-radius: 50%;
 
  height: @random;
  width: 3em;
  background-color: @color;
  animation: circleSize 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes circleSize {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(0,0);
  }
}
```

The random number is generated only during the first render and is not changed during subsequent re-renders. How do I go about it ?

Comment: If you put an empty array as dependencies for `useEffect`, it would run only on mounting and unmounting. So if you want your code to be ran on every render, you should remove the empty array. That would run the effect on every render.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is use a 'css-in-js' approach.
React only re-renders components that changed and your css is static right now. If you define your styles in a js file and pass your random number to this file every time your App's interval runs - you'll get your re-renders.